How to remove UU i.e. Busy state for i2c 2 line for Bullseye Debian Beaglebone Black?
I am working on Bullseye Debian image on Beaglebone Black and I was trying to connect my FRAM device on i2c2 line i.e. Pin 21 and 22. I am getting busy state i.e. UU in that for Addresses 0x54 to 0x57.
i2c_2 busy state image for address 0x54 to 0x57
devices info in /sys/bus/i2c/devices
devices info in /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/at24
I also followed the steps mentioned in post
Set up expansion EEPROM i2c-2 BeagleBoneBlack Rev-C.
https://groups.google.com/g/beagleboard/c/NG8cDWuv2Y0/m/69vk5F5ZAgAJ. By Robert Nelson but it did not work.
When i comment out the “enable_uboot_cape_universal=1” in uEnv.txt file, it does not turn ON after reboot.
Can anyone please help me in this?

It depends what you want to achieve. Most likely your system already recognizes your chip and loads the respective driver, means you may read/modify its contents already from the shell. Hence you need to clarify what you want: Option 1) unbind the driver (https://lwn.net/Articles/143397/); Option 2) find the actual device in the Linux device model and see how it looks like (ls -l /sys/bus/i2c/devices/... and so on); Option 3) something else, please clarify! (Currently voted to close this because of lack of clarity what this is all about.)

Hello 0andriy, thank you for the comment. I tried the option 1 before but it does work but soon as i reboot the BeagleBone then it again shows UU i.e. it does not hold that state after booting up. Option 2 i saw that before and i have added the image as well in my question above. it shows its been occupied. I had made this work earlier on my Buster debian image but when i try to do same for my Bullseye debian imag

You kept unclear about your intention. For me it's very awkward that somebody wants to unbind the existing driver (in case it does its job).

I want to unbind it so that i can use those address space for my FRAM device. My intension is to connect my FRAM device to i2c2 line (pin P9 21 and 22) and use all the address space starting from 0x50 to 0x57 which i am unable to use it right now because of this i2c address busy state issue.

Still unclear, why do you want to unbind existed driver?
